# Questions got serial down-votes, revenge?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, serial-voting

While I'm reviewing my profile, I did notice a strange behavior especially on my 0 votes questions:

[image]

As you can note here, 4 votes down on the 4 so different questions in 1 minutes, that target my 0 votes questions to be -1 fo all, which this is an annoying part here!

I don't really bother myself with this, but still, I want to understand how to prevent that or report that.

I tried to find a question similar to this, but I found nothing talking about this case exactly, (or I was searching for incorrect words).

Any explanation and how to report this?
Especially that down caster seems smart guy trying to avoid the auto-detect system of stack overflow system.

Comment: I've invalidated the votes - I will not go into details, but this wasn't a single person.

Comment: @Oded thanks, I know it could be possible to get this case somehow, but if I only was so active and with big activity, it was odd for someone with the only 2K rep to get this case, also 4 downvotes with no comment on any.

Comment: Comments are not required to issue a downvote.  There is nothing strange about not leaving a comment when you issue a downvote.  Something else just happened to being going on.  Don't expect comments when a downvote is issued because it's not required